# Table Scan Which Columns Are Checked?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

How exactly does a table scan work?

Here is what I know:

- A table scan searches the entire table.
- A clustered index scan searches just whatever column(s) are defined on that index.

Let's pretend we have this scenario:

**table_a**

Columns: ID, City, Country

I have a clustered index on `City`.

The query I run is this:

```
select city
from table_a
where city = 'austin'
```

Actual questions:

1. In this scenario would the table scan only look at the `city` column or would it check the ID, City, and country columns.
2. If the table scan only searches one column, is it safe to say that the table scan and the index scan have the same performance?

Edit Part 1:

Google search wrote:

> When the table scan occurs SQL Server reads all the rows and columns into memory. When the Index Scan occurs, it's going to read all the rows and only the columns in the index.

Comment: "A clustered index scan searches just whatever column(s) are defined on that index." - that's incorrect. A clustered index scan IS a table scan: it visits every page in the table, because in SQL Server the (single) clustered index IS the table. Even though it examines just the columns required for the query it still reads every page.

Comment: Why do they have different names if they are the same thing? Are they only the same thing in certain scenarios?

Comment: "Why do they have different names if they are the same thing?" - perhaps ask Microsoft! Originally the term table scan was used to cover heaps and clustered tables. Later the terms were split (AFAIK). BUT, Clustered Index Scan == Table scan.

Comment: No, I am not trying to be a jerk, just trying to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: Also, I just edited my post. I think you might be incorrect.

Comment: I am not incorrect, but may have confused. By read the page I mean it has to be read into memory from disk, if it  is not already there in memory. (and talking about normal indexes not column store)

Comment: When I did a Google search, it says what I posted in my edit. That being said, I don't understand how they are the same thing.

Comment: An index scan of a clustered index IS a table scan! Because the one and only clustered index IS the table.

Comment: But the definition says all of the rows and columns are read in the table scan and the index scan only reads the values in the index?

Comment: When you are in school, you ask questions to learn. I'm simply poking holes at you to make sure I understand correctly. No need to get so upset my friend

Answer (score 0):

Look at the execution plan. I would expect a clustered index seek so that only those rows with the specified City are touched. If you search on a non-indexed column, a clustered index scan will be performed so all rows are touched but only qualifying rows are returned.

Only the columns needed by the query will be extracted from the rows and extraneous columns will not be examined during the scan or seek operation.